# Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in the complex plane, then find the set of all possible values of $\int_C \frac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Please cross-check my answer and let me know if there be any short process to determine the result.

> **Question:** Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in the complex plane, then find the set of all possible values of $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}~.$$

**Answer:**
Here $~f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}~.$

The poles of $~f(z)~$ are at $~z=0,\pm1~$.

At $~z=0:$ $$g(z)=(z-0)f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z^2)}$$is analytic at $~z=0~$, so the pole is simple and $$\text{Res}(f, 0) = g(0) = 1~.$$
At $~z=1:$ $$g(z)=(z-1)f(z)=\frac{-1}{z(1+z)}$$is analytic at $~z=1~$, so the pole is simple and $$\text{Res}(f, 1) = g(1) = -\frac 12~.$$
At $~z=-1:$ $$g(z)=(z+1)f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)}$$is analytic at $~z=-1~$, so the pole is simple and$$\text{Res}(f, -1) = g(-1) = -\frac 12~.$$

**Case I:** If only $~z=0~$ lies inside $C$, then by residue theorem,
$$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, 0)\right]=2\pi i~.$$

**Case II:** If only $~z=1~$ lies inside $C$, then by residue theorem,
$$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, 1)\right]=-\pi i~.$$

**Case III:** If only $~z=-1~$ lies inside $C$, then by residue theorem,
$$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, -1)\right]=-\pi i~.$$

**Case IV:** If $~z=0~$ and $~z=1~$ lies inside $C$, then by residue theorem, $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, 0)+\text{Res}(f, 1)\right]=\pi i~.$$

**Case V:** If $~z=0~$ and $~z=-1~$ lies inside $C$, then by residue theorem, $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, 0)+\text{Res}(f, -1)\right]=\pi i~.$$

**Case VI:** If $~z=1~$ and $~z=-1~$ lies inside $C$, then by residue theorem, $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, 1)+\text{Res}(f, -1)\right]=-2\pi i~.$$

**Case VII:** If $~z=0~,~z=1~,~z=-1~$ all lie inside $C$, then by residue theorem, $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=2\pi i\left[\text{Res}(f, 0)+\text{Res}(f, 1)+\text{Res}(f, -1)\right]=0~.$$

**Case VIII:** If $~z=0~,~z=1~,~z=-1~$ all lie outside $C$, then by residue theorem, $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z(1-z^2)}=0~.$$

Hence the possible set of values is $~\fbox{$\{0,~\pm \pi i,~\pm 2\pi i\}$}~$.